# Combine name abbreviations out of a list when date is the same

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently I am working on a vacation planner for my colleagues.
Each month is separated in days as well as a list where I want the name abbreviations of colleagues who are on vacation that date.
The list of name abbreviations and the date are in a table next to the 'calender'.

**edit**

The abbreviations of each person should only be cells when the from-until date is equal or in between to display who is on vacation that day.

**edit**

[Calender with name abbreviations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GY7hR.png)

[Table where colleagues enter their vacation manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFih2.png)

My problem is, that I am not able to combine the abbreviations if two people have vacation on the same day. I would like to have no specifc order, so my colleagues just can enter the days one after the other, not paying attention if the dates are in order.

Is there a formula to do it for me? (kinda like 'Count If' but more like 'Combine If') :)

I hope it is understandable what I am trying to achive.

Thanks for your help & have a nice day.

Comment: Research `TEXTJOIN()` and see if it's supported by your version of Excel.

Comment: It does, but I dont know how to solve my issue with the 'if'-part. If I use TEXTJOIN() it would connect all strings, not paying attention if the date is relevant or not.

Comment: You can use a nested `IF()` in the third parameter. Something like `=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(<rest of your logic>.....`

Comment: Thank you JvdV for helping. :)
A nested IF() could work, but is there a simpler way? Otherwise I would have to check all the cells with an IF(). Something like SUMPRODUCT(), using matrix to check all the possible values, but only with strings or so.

Comment: Ok, I found out what my actual problem was. Somehow my IF() does not allow an AND() connection when I try to compare the from/until date with the date in the cell. Now it seems to work. If you like you can write a respone so I can mark it as the correct answer.
Thanks for your help JvdV. :)